# Differential packaging

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When upgrading an application, the `Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage` command throws errors for every code package whose version number has not changed (it's saying the content has changed, even though the code hasn't). I know there is a feature that allows creating partial packages, but I was not able to use it. My questions are:

1. How is the content of the code package checked for changes? Binary comparison?
2. How to construct the partial package (Just remove the Code directories after VS builds the package? Edit the `ServiceManifest.xml` file?)
3. How to run `Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage` (What's the image store URL? How to pass that parameter to the standard deployment script?)

I'd appreciate a thorough example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to do partial upgrades, this is how I've done it:

Given

```
app1 1.0.0
  service1 1.0.0
    code 1.0.0
    config 1.0.0
  service2 1.0.0
    code 1.0.0
    config 1.0.0
```

And you want to update only Service 1 to version 1.0.1 as shown below:

```
app1 1.0.1
  service1 1.0.1
    code 1.0.1
    config 1.0.1
  service2 1.0.0
    code 1.0.0
    config 1.0.0
```

In your Service1, update the ServiceManifest.xml to have correct version numbers (the service itself and the different packages you want to upgrade).
Then, in your service2 folder, delete everything except the ServiceManifest.xml.

In your ApplicationManifest.xml, you should keep the ServiceManifestImport for Service2 at version 1.0.0. Also update the versionnumber for ServiceManifestImport for Service1.

After that is done, you should be able to do a:

```
Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage $packagePath -ImageStoreConnectionString $ImageStoreConnectionString
```

to validate that the package works. What this does (as far as I understand) is it uses the local package along with the currently deployed package, and those two combined should then equal a valid complete package.

So, basically, the only thing that changes is:

- You remove the things you don't want in your package (but you keep
  the ServiceManifest.xml)
- You update the version numbers in the services that have changed
- You update the version numbers in the application manifest for both the application, and the changed services.

Also, see this documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-upgrade-advanced/#upgrade-with-a-diff-package

Regarding getting the image store to use for the **Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage** call (you can find it all by looking at the default deploy scripts, but here's what you need):

```
Open powershell
Connect to your cluster (Connect-ServiceFabricCluster ...)
Execute the following commands:

$ClusterManifestRaw = Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest
$ClusterManifestXml = [xml]$ClusterManifestRaw
$ManagementSection = $ClusterManifestXml.ClusterManifest.FabricSettings.Section | ? { $_.Name -eq "Management" }
$ImageStoreConnectionString = $ManagementSection .ChildNodes | ? { $_.Name -eq "ImageStoreConnectionString" } | Select-Object -Expand Value
```

Comment: is it still the case that it's preferable to do these upgrades from powershell rather than directly from vs?

Comment: The VS tooling for local deploy is a lot better now than what it was a year ago, but we still use PS to deploy, even locally. That's our preferences at least. I guess it all depends on if it does what you need and what you are comfortable with.

Comment: can i take a peek at your scripts?

Comment: We've built our own in-house packager to deal with everything for us. The code and docs for it is here: https://github.com/andersosthus/ServiceFabricPackager
It's been working great for us for for about 1.5 years now, so for our deploys we just have simple powershell scripts that first call our packager and then the SF powershell commands to upload and register.

Answer (score 6):

Service Fabric supports differential packages but upgrades with differential packages hasn't been completely integrated with Visual Studio yet. But you can do it manually.

1. Yes it's binary comparison.
2. So in a differential package, you increment the versions only for packages (code, config, and data) that have changed. If the binaries have changed for a package whose version has not changed - which can just be from a recompilation - then you can simply omit its files from the final application package.
3. The image store can be an external location (like Azure blob storage) but the simplest option is the built-in image store service, which is used by default in the SDK and in Azure. To use that, simply use "fabric:ImageStore" for the image store string: Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage -ApplicationPackagePath /path/to/package -ImageStoreConnectionString fabric:ImageStore

Here's an example of a diff package. Imagine you have the following:

```
app1 1.0.0
  service1 1.0.0
    code 1.0.0
    config 1.0.0
  service2 1.0.0
    code 1.0.0
    config 1.0.0
```

And you want to upgrade only the code package of service1:

```
app1 2.0.0            <-- new version
  service1 2.0.0      <-- new version
    code 2.0.0        <-- new version
    config 1.0.0
  service2 1.0.0
    code 1.0.0
    config 1.0.0
```

You update the versions in your application and service manifests, but you only include the packages that have changed in the final application package. Your application package would simply look like this:

```
app1/
  service1/
    code/
```

The packages whose version numbers haven't changed aren't included. Note that you *could* include those packages, but only if they are identical (binary diff) to the packages of the same version currently registered for the application in the cluster, in which case they will simply be ignored.

A quick and easy way to generate one of these is to use the **Package** command in Visual Studio (right-click the application and select Package). Then go to the output directory and simply delete the directories for packages whose versions haven't changed.

Comment: Just delete the package files from the application package, nothing else. Take another look at the example in my response. The application package (files on disk that you copy to the image store) should look like the directory structure shown there, assuming only the code package of service1 is a new version.

Comment: @VaclavTurecek I made changes to one service and left the directory in the package and deleted the other services directories that did not change. I get an error when testing the package: `ServiceManifest.xml is missing for service ApiPkg`

Comment: any follow-up on this from @VaclavTurecek?