# Debug only specific service in Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, visual-studio-debugging

I wonder if there's an option to run locally service fabric application but to choose the specific services to run in debug.

I mean, I have many services (about 40) and I'd like to have an option to debug only one service without having all the others running too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Those running services don't interfere if you just put breakpoints in the one service you are interested in, do they?

Comment: You're right, but since we're talking about many services, it takes some time to deploy the application to the local cluster.
So every time I want to debug I need to wait until the whole application starts and it takes 3-4 minutes.
If it's possible to run only one service I'd prefer that.

Comment: @Bar Maltabashi, Like Alex's suggestion, how about using the Attach to process debugging?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, it's possible I guess but that still means that all the other services are running locally. I wonder if there's an option to choose which services should be deployed to the local cluster when running the app.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can deploy a particular service and attach to it using Degug -> Attach to Process... 
More details on upgrading can be found here: [Upgrade Service Fabric Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446890/upgrade-service-fabric-application)

Comment: Indeed. Publish from VS (do not hit F5), the app and its services will be deployed and started. Then attach debugger to particular service process. 1 node cluster configuration will simplify the whole process easier.

Comment: @Alex Riabov, Ok, but is it possible to actually deploy one service and ignore the rest?

Comment: @BarMaltabashi yes, you can use diff packaging and app upgrade. Diff packaging allows you to define an application package that only contains the package parts that you wish to upgrade. Detailed information regarding diff packaging: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-upgrade-advanced/ . In a nutshell, you have to update version numbers only for service you want to update