# Deploy Service Fabric services individually

Tags: azure-service-fabric

From the documentation and examples I've seen it seems that the preferred way to deploy Service Fabric services is to package them all up into an application package.

If I have 30 services and I make a change to one of them I'm not interested in having my CI server pull down the entire repository, build the solution, package it and then have Service Fabric decide that only one service changed and so only one should be updated.

Is there a way to create an application package with just one service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to perform a partial upgrade (Differential Packaging). See here. [Differential packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873891/differential-packaging/34886586)

Comment: Thanks for linking that, it's good to know that it is supported. However, if I update one service and delete the other services from the package when I run the powershell test application package cmdlet it returns an error saying that files are missing. I tried leaving the directory of the service that wasn't changed and just deleting the code folder and it still didn't work.

Comment: You need to specify the ImageStoreConnectionString parameter when calling Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage so that it can know where to look for the original package that you're diffing against.