# Service Fabric upgrade with a diff package

Tags: azure-devops, diff, azure-service-fabric

How do you perform upgrade with diff package in Service Fabric trough VSTS release pipeline? I’m fully aware of how the concept with works and I have read through the documentations (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-advanced#upgrade-with-a-diff-package) but how do you configure and setup? Currently we have one application with 15 services so can understand our need to do upgrade with diff package. I would like to know what steps I need to do to have diff deployment in place through VSTS. I know that you can do the versioning trough VS and then build and release trough VSTS but is that the correct way to do it?

How our pipeline looks like

1. Token replace where we update the Cloud.xml
2. Deploying Service Fabric application to the cluster

**Release task**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the versioning through VSTS, you can have a try with this extension : [Service Fabric Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aelij.ServiceFabricTools)) which applies versioning to a Service Fabric package... then build and release...

Just configure CI/CD to deploy the application, please refer to [Deploy an application with CI/CD to a Service Fabric cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-app-with-cicd-vsts) for details.

Edit verisons of service fabric manifest, check `Use Diff Package` under `upgrade settings` in `Service Fabric Application Deployment` task...

Reference below threads:

- [Continuous Deployment of Service Fabric Apps using VSTS (or TFS)](https://colinsalmcorner.com/post/continuous-deployment-of-service-fabric-apps-using-vsts-or-tfs)
- [Deployment for Service Fabric service version upgrade fails on VSTS Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316938/deployment-for-service-fabric-service-version-upgrade-fails-on-vsts-release)

Comment: Hi,

Thank for the response. Im already using that extentison. The problem I have is that all the services gets updated when i do Package versioning.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the response. Im already using that extentison. The problem I have is that all the services gets updated when i do Package versioning. Even if i have only changed the service "Service Test.A.AAPkg" in the application "Application Test.ServiceFabric.ApplicationType". The reason for that could be that i have following checked in the ServiceFabric Deployment task (see the picture ServiceFabricDeploymentTask)

Application Test.ServiceFabric.ApplicationType     1.0.36.20180723.2    -> 1.0.36.20180723.2+Release-1

Service Test.A.AAPkg   1.0.9.20180723.2   ->   1.0.9.20180723.2+Release-1
     CodePackage Code                                   1.0.9.20180723.2 ->     1.0.9.20180723.2+afa0508121979034ce6f804089155759287612d2 
     ConfigPackage Config                               1.0.9.20180723.2 ->     1.0.9.20180723.2+e4b80262f4b22005c1e235f31f7aaad9c8466bc1

Service Test.B.BBPkg   1.0.9.20180723.2   ->   1.0.9.20180723.2+Release-1
     CodePackage Code                                   1.0.13.20180723.2 ->     1.0.13.20180723.2+4b6fcbe6c13fbe5fdd36ba22ef046b299b29e1f1 
     ConfigPackage Config                               1.0.6.20180723.2 ->     1.0.6.20180723.2+604664e623f047a813eee50695ee84149eae9b91

Service Test.C.CCPkg               1.0.9.20180723.2   ->   1.0.9.20180723.2+Release-1
     CodePackage Code                                   1.0.9.20180723.2 ->     1.0.9.20180723.2+e1a9aabff2d35c56391634f3bbfc7638aa9334c6 
     ConfigPackage Config                               1.0.9.20180723.2 ->     1.0.9.20180723.2+77d23eaba7dbfc1d2e8f86da9003007cf5671b3b

Service Test.D.DDPkg   1.0.9.20180723.2   ->   1.0.9.20180723.2+Release-1
     CodePackage Code                                   1.0.9.20180723.2 ->     1.0.9.20180723.2+a365e71ffd686617f06e566351dc1a91d9968635 
     ConfigPackage Config                               1.0.9.20180723.2 ->     1.0.9.20180723.2+8c1afa2b6ec57792072016ccecfd3e3d4454e9c1

[ServiceFabricDeploymentTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1b0W.png)
[ExtensionTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM6XC.png)