# Error while upgrading Azure Service Fabric through VSTS CI/CD

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using VSTS to setup CI/CD for service fabric build and deployment. First deploy goes through without error but second update deployment gives me below error.

> The content in ConfigPackage Name:Config and Version:1.0.0.20180312.1
>   in Service Manifest 'SampleWebPkg' has changed, but the version number
>   is the same.

I followed the below instruction

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-deploy-app-with-cicd-vsts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you have updated the service binaries and didn't update the manifests, the manifest points to the same version as before but the binaries are different.

> An example how this might occur is when you rebuild your service and
>   deploy a new version without changing the version numbers in the
>   manifest files

Check:

- If the service version in the servicesmanifest.xml has been updated compared to previous one, if not, upgrade it.
- The service version in applicationmanifest.xml has been updated compared to previous one

Comment: thanks for the info i checked serivcemanifest.xml and <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0.20180312.7" /> version is not getting updated. in vsts how to i make sure this gets updated as part of build?

Comment: There is a Build Step called 'Update Service Fabric App Versions' that updates the service version of your service based on the build number or pattern you define. You will have to run it as part of the build process.

Comment: I am using 'Update Service Fabric Manifests' as part of my build process. what I have noticed recently is if I uncheck 'Update only if changed' then <ConfigPackage Name="Config" Version="1.0.0.20180312.7" /> gets updated and deployment goes through. is this correct way of deploying?

Comment: Update only if changed is a source of mess, because it tries to identify if the services has changed to update only the ones changed, but it is not so easy to keep track of it. If you want to got that route, I would recommend you take a look at Differential packaging on service fabric.

Comment: thanks. can you please provide me more info where I can read about Differential packaging on service fabric thorough VSTS? How can i get the deployment to update if I keep "Update only if changed" enabled?

Comment: You can find more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-advanced#upgrade-with-a-diff-package

Comment: And Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873891/differential-packaging/34886586#34886586