# Prevent Visual Studio from rebuilding after packaging Service Fabric with diff packaging

Tags: c#, service-fabric-stateless, azure-service-fabric

I am having a lot of issues upgrading a Service Fabric application.

My original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658376/cannot-upgrade-service-fabric-service-due-to-package-contents-changed-when-they/51701973?noredirect=1#comment90367081_51701973).

I am raising a new one now as this relates specifically to diff packaging.

I have modified my package to remove the services I don't want to touch.

But when I publish via Visual Studio, it does a full build.

If I try to run the PowerShell script on its own by right clicking on it, it does not work:

```
 Cannot validate argument on parameter 'PublishProfileFile'. The "Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf" validation script for the argument with value 
"MYPATH\Scripts\..\PublishProfiles\Local.xml" did not return a result of True. Determine why the 
validation script failed, and then try the command again.
At MYPATH\Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1:173 char:39
```

Can anyone suggest anything please?

How can I run this script in PowerShell without errors?  I don't have much experience with PowerShell and I definitely don't want to have to create an upgrade script from scratch!

At the moment I am trying to get this working in a local 5-node cluster.

Answer (score 1):

ok I got around this by creating a called to a command file which clears out the unrequired packages

```
<Target Name="AfterPackage" AfterTargets="Package">
    <Exec Command="Upgrade\upgrade.cmd" />
  </Target>
```

There is another issue now but I am going to create a new question for that